# Java EE 8 - MVC 1.0 release date

Tags: jakarta-ee, release, jakarta-mvc

When I can expect realising full or nearly full version of MVC 1.0. 
I'm interesting to continue developing my web app in this technology as I don't like to do my own MVC with Servlets/JSP or use WebForms-like JSF/Facelets. I'm interesting in rather very basic features of MVC 1.0 as I will try to use more HTML5/javascript/angular.js or something like that to create front-end. 
I think about developing front-end from half of this year and it may be with beta of MVC 1.0 and production will be at the end of year? when MVC 1.0 will be implemented.
When JBoss will launch their implementation of MVC 1.0 compatible with Wildfly as I'm developing on this and it isn't as easy to switch to glassfish/ozark as I previously thought.

Answer (score 1):

On the [JSR 371: Model-View-Controller (MVC 1.0) Specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=371) page an update was made in July 2015 about expected milestones:

```
2015.07.14:
The schedule has been updated:
Q4 2015 Early Draft 2
Q1 2016 Public Review
Q3 2016 Proposed Final Draft
H1 2017 Final Release
```

So, Looks like 2017 sometime.

Comment: Ok what means Public Review exactly? Proposed Final Draft would contain most of features? So I can assume that they will be in final release and start developing with Ozark my web app and then after some months of development deploy it in 2017 with final release. I mean whether I can start in half of 2016 start developing front end with aim to deploy it in 2017 when final relase will be launched.

Comment: I don't know how stable Ozark is, I've never tried to use it. That's probably a question for the [Ozark Group](https://ozark.java.net/index.html). Try them.

Comment: Do these dates still hold? Ozark development stopped completely in October 2016. That's 4 months were absolutely nothing happened, so unless they're done already (don't think so) all those dates have to be extended by at least 4 months?

Answer (score 1):

It won't be released as part of Java EE 8 anymore.

Since October 2016 it has been abandoned and at February 2017 the whole spec is transferred to an individual, Ivar Grimstad. See also a.o. [this article](https://adtmag.com/articles/2017/02/08/oracle-mvc-community.aspx):

> ## Oracle Transfers Ownership of MVC to the Community
>
> <sup>By John K. Waters 02/08/2017</sup>
>
> Oracle Corp. is transferring full ownership of the Model-View-Controller (MVC) specification to the Java community, the company announced. Once the transfer is completed, long-time contributor Ivar Grimstad will serve as a purely community spec lead for [JSR 371](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=371), the MVC 1.0 standard.
>
> The previous MVC spec leads, Oracle's Santiago Pericasgeertsen, and Manfred Riem, [announced](https://java.net/projects/mvc-spec/lists/users/archive/2017-01/message/0) the initiation of a Transfer Ballot to the Expert Group of the Java Community Process (JCP) on Jan. 17. That ballot closed on January 31st, and the Executive Committee of the JCP [approved](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/results?id=5907) the transfer. The community will now be responsible for moving the MVC 1.0 spec forward on its own.
>
> [...]

In other words, [Ivar Grimstad](https://twitter.com/ivar_grimstad) will now continue developing MVC as a separate library/framework.

Comment: I think that when there are this all new front end SPA, PWA technologies like Angular 2+, React, etc. the backend MVC framework other then JAX-RS specification has little sense.